# Flask Python sqlite3: primary key in table is null instead of int

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

When I input data into a table, I get null instead of int for the primary key.  How can I fix this?

This is my table:

```
conn.execute('CREATE TABLE lists (listid INT PRIMARY KEY, book TEXT, chapter INT)')
```

I input data into `lists` with this code:

```
@app.route('/addbook', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def addbook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        bt = request.form['bt']
        bc = request.form['bc']

        con =  sql.connect("seei.db")
        cur = con.cursor()

        cur.execute("INSERT INTO lists (book, chapter) VALUES (?, ?)", (bt, bc))

        con.commit()
        con.close()
        return render_template("addconcepts.html")
```

and this html:

```
<body>

<form action="{{ url_for('addbook') }}" method="POST">
  Book Title<br>
  <input type="text" name="bt" /><br>

  Book Chapter<br>
  <input type="text" name="bc" /><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>

</body>
```

Comment: did you `import sqlite3 as sql`? otherwise `sql.connect()` would be wrong

Comment: I did `import sqlite3 as sql`

Comment: You should put semicolon after the sql query

Comment: like this  `cur.execute("INSERT INTO lists (book, chapter) VALUES (?, ?)", (bt, bc));` ?  That didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [SQLite documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) (emphasis mine):

> With one exception noted below, if a rowid table has a primary key
>   that consists of a single column and the declared type of that column
>   is "INTEGER" in any mixture of upper and lower case, then the column
>   becomes an alias for the rowid. Such a column is usually referred to
>   as an "integer primary key". **A PRIMARY KEY column only becomes an
>   integer primary key if the declared type name is exactly "INTEGER".**
>   Other integer type names like "INT" or "BIGINT" or "SHORT INTEGER" or
>   "UNSIGNED INTEGER" causes the primary key column to behave as an
>   ordinary table column with integer affinity and a unique index, not as
>   an alias for the rowid.

Create your table as:

```
CREATE TABLE lists (listid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, book TEXT, chapter INT)
```

Answer (score -1):

> `cur.execute("INSERT INTO lists (book, chapter) VALUES (?, ?)", (bt, bc))`

This would produce a `ProgrammingError` for incorrect number of bindings. Instead use:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO lists (book, chapter) VALUES (?, ?)", [(bt, bc)])
```

Also, in your `CREATE TABLE` command, you would need to change `INT` to `INTEGER` for the autoincrement behavior.

Comment: This is incorrect. The syntax of the original statement is fine. Your proposed correction only has one parameter (a tuple).

Comment: @glibdud, `request.form['foo']` evaluates to a string. As it is, if the string happened to be more than 2 characters (i.e. the number of bindings in the SQL statement), that would produce an error.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. Apparently I had `executemany` in my code instead. Didn't know that changed behavior.